# How to display video controls in ExoMedia Library

Tags: android, android-studio, github, exoplayer

I am using the ExoMedia Library for playing the hls in my android app.
But I am not able to display the video controls like seek button, it only displays the Play Button and nothing else. When I try to use the EMVideoView the app crashes. I am using Android Studio Canary 4.
Here is the Code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.devbrackets.android.exomedia.ui.widget.VideoView
    android:id="@+id/video_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:useDefaultControls="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here if Instead of VideoView I use EMVideoView then the app crashes.

```
 public class ExternalPlayer extends AppCompatActivity implements 
  OnPreparedListener {

private FullScreenListener fullScreenListener = new FullScreenListener();
private VideoView videoView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_external_player);
    setupVideoView();
    initUiFlags();
    if (videoView.getVideoControls() != null) {
        videoView.getVideoControls().setVisibilityListener(new ControlsVisibilityListener());
    }
}

private void setupVideoView() {
    // Make sure to use the correct VideoView import
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String link = intent.getStringExtra("url");
    videoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.video_view);
    videoView.setOnPreparedListener(ExternalPlayer.this);
    videoView.showControls();
    //Uri coming from MOMScreen to play
    videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(link));
}

@Override
public void onPrepared() {
    videoView.start();
}



@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    exitFullscreen();
}

private void goFullscreen() {
    setUiFlags(true);
}

private void exitFullscreen() {
    setUiFlags(false);
}

private void initUiFlags() {
    int flags = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        flags |= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION;
    }

    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    if (decorView != null) {
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(flags);
        decorView.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(fullScreenListener);
    }
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
private void setUiFlags(boolean fullscreen) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        if (decorView != null) {
            decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(fullscreen ? getFullscreenUiFlags() : View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE);
        }
    }
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
private int getFullscreenUiFlags() {
    int flags = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        flags |= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;
    }

    return flags;
}

private class FullScreenListener implements View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener {
    @Override
    public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
        if ((visibility & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN) == 0) {
            videoView.showControls();

        }
    }
}


private class ControlsVisibilityListener implements VideoControlsVisibilityListener {
    @Override
    public void onControlsShown() {
        // No additional functionality performed

    }

    @Override
    public void onControlsHidden() {
        goFullscreen();
    }
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

}

I have tried all the methods to display the control as per my knowledge but none of them worked.
Any suggestions please....

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue. Then it got fixed with the help of below repository. You can also refer it, if you are some other. It may help you.

https://github.com/brianwernick/ExoMedia

The video controls are explained in the below link.
https://devbrackets.com/dev/libs/docs/exomedia/3.1.0/com/devbrackets/android/exomedia/ui/widget/VideoControls.html#setNextButtonEnabled-boolean-

more specifically setNextButtonEnabled() and setNextButtonRemoved()

Comment: mVideoView = (EMVideoView) findViewById(R.id.video_view);

  VideoControls controls = mVideoView.getVideoControls();
  controls.setNextButtonEnabled(true);
   controls.setPreviousButtonEnabled(true);

Comment: I am not able to use EMVideoView when I use it the app crashes